# Array List looping for a duplicate value

Tags: for-loop, arraylist, drools

I am looking if there is an "easy" or simple way to make an array of something, Lets say Icecreams.. this would be a class of icecream with various Attributes (ID, flavour, Size, scoops), i would like to run an array that gathers every ice cream ordered and then searches through this list for any duplicate values (2+ same size)

First idea i had was a for loop that creates the array than grabs the ice cream ID for the first instance, and checks its "flavour" against the array, if no duplicate is found the ID is increased by 1 (ID++) and then that Ice creams flavour is ran in the array, if a match is found i would set a Boolean to true.

Every approach i seem to take appears to be rather long winded and i haven't got one working as of yet. hoping some fresh/more experienced eyes would help on this.

In answer to below;
The XML would hold something like below

```
<iceCream id=1>
    <flavour>chocolate</flavour>
    <scoops>5</scoops>
</iceCream>
<iceCream id=2>
    <flavour>banana</flavour>
    <scoops>2</scoops>
</iceCream>
```

I would want to use drools (probably an array list?) to gather each icecream tag and allow me to check if any of the icecreams have the same flavour and output something (set a boolean to true) if a match is found, My understand was to make an array then run each icecream though the array by using its ID to identify it and inside each loop do ID +1 (int ID = 1) then in the lopp ID++. Aswell as search through the flavour childtag.

```
int ID = 0;
boolean match = false;
ArrayList iceCreams = new ArrayList($cont.getIceCreams());

for(iceCream $Flavour: (ArrayList<iceCream>)iceCreams)
    {
       ID++
       if($Flavour.getFlavour().equals(icecream with id of (ID variable).getFlavour)
       {
         match = true;
       }
    }
if(match)
{etc etc etc}
```

Something along these lines if this helps?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  Do you mean something like if `ice_cream[flavor_0] == chocolate` or something like `ice_cream[flavor_0] == ice_cream[flavor_1]`?

Comment: See above, may still be a little unclear. having a hectic day and my brain has given in

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have control over the first array creation, why dont you make sure that while insertion, you insert only the icecreams that are unique. So, while you are inserting into the array say ID=1, first iterate through the array and check if there is an icecream in the array with ID as 1, if not you put this into the array and do other stuff.
2) Searching part: now while inserting, make sure that you are doing so based on the ascending oder of IDs, so you can perform binary search for the same.

Note: I dont know drools, i have just posted a logic as per my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know drools either, but I'll post the some pseudo code for what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
for(i = 0; i < len(ice_cream_array); i++)
{
   for(j = (i + 1); j < len(ice_cream_array); j++)
   {
       if (ice_cream_array[i] == ice_cream_array[j])
           break from inner loop
       else
           there is no match

   }
}
```

You may also want to look up [bubble sorts and binary searches](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/27067/).